# Register TextFields with TextArea with JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with `JTextField`, `JRadioButton`. I can't register them with `TextArea`. I need to enter name and age and salary and display them on `TextArea`.

```
package gui2;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class GUI2 {

 JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2, 2));
 JPanel labelFields = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2, 2));
 JPanel labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 3, 4));
 JPanel fields = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 3, 4));
/* JTextField name1 = new JTextField(20);
 JTextField age1 = new JTextField(20);
 JTextField s = new JTextField(20);*/ 
 JPanel guiCenter = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(1, 0));
/* JRadioButton male = new JRadioButton("male");
 JRadioButton female = new JRadioButton("Female");*/
 JPanel gu = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
 //  JTextArea e = new JTextArea(5, 30); 

   GUI2() {
      labelFields.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Employee"));
      labels.setBorder(new TitledBorder(" Info "));
      fields.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Please enter your info"));
      labels.add(new JLabel("Name"));
      fields.add(name1);
      labels.add(new JLabel("Age"));
      fields.add(age1);
      labels.add(new JLabel("Salary"));
      fields.add(s);
      labelFields.add(labels, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      labelFields.add(fields, BorderLayout.EAST);
      guiCenter.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Gender"));
      ButtonGroup bG = new ButtonGroup();
      bG.add(male);
      bG.add(female);
      guiCenter.add(male, BorderLayout.WEST);
      guiCenter.add(female, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      gu.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Employee Info"));
      gu.add(new JScrollPane(e));
      gui.add(guiCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      gui.add(labelFields, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      gui.add(gu, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
      int input = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, null, null, JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
      for (int i =0 ; i < JOptionPane.OK_OPTION ; i++){
        if(input == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
           e.setText(age1.getText());
           e.setText(name1.getText());
           e.setText(s.getText());
          }
        }
      }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new GUI2();
        }
   } );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the content of the JTextArea **e**

```
e.setText(e.getText()+" "+age1.getText());
e.setText(e.getText()+" "+name1.getText());
e.setText(e.getText()+" "+s.getText());
```

PS : I don't know if you're know what you are doing or not , but your textFields are not declared , because the declaration is  in a comment.

Comment: i know that but i do this to make it take attention :) Anyway in my program its without the comment